# Python native notifications

Tags: python, user-interface, notifications

Is it even possible to create notifications in python GUI?

Here are my requirements:

- Should work when app is minimised
- Can be called anytime
- function should take 2 params, title and notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how (from a notification program that i made long ago):

```
import Tkinter, time, tkMessageBox

top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.withdraw() #to make the main window invisible

def notify(title='Default title', notification='Default notification'):
   tkMessageBox.showinfo(title, notification)

notify()
notify('Yo','Did you know this is a notification!')
```

meets all your requirements plus is written in standard python.

Comment: real fast, i wish i could award you more, but i can only accept. :)